# How to make full smart contract token?

Tags: ether, myetherwallet, tokens, build-from-source

I want to make my smart contract, but I have some questions.

for example my new coin name is : Ghost and it's based on Eth.

- how much ETH should I have in my wallet to create this smart contract?
- After creation of my new coin "Ghost", and when someone want to send 10 Ghosts to another one, what about the fees of transaction, will it be in ETH or Ghost? and how I can control on it? the amount of fees and which address should got this fees?
- after I deploy the smart contract on mist what the next ?

Regards

Comment: the price in ICO it's should be mentioned on smart contract or it's how the owner want it to be ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @pabloruiz55's answer:

> how much ETH should I have in my wallet to create this smart contract?

The transaction fee for deploying a smart contract depends on its content. You could estimate the gas required for contract creation from [remix-online solidity compiler](http://remix.ethereum.org).

- Simply paste your code in compiler tab
- Click on `start to compile` to compile the code
- If the code is compiled successfully you could check the gas required for deploying your smart contract.
- You could also get estimated gas for all the function of your contract (including transfer)

**Note:**

Ethers required for a transaction (including deploying a contract) is governed by a formula:

```
transactionCost = gas*gasPrice
```

You already estimated gas from the remix and you can choose gas price as per your convenience. For reference of safe lowest gas price have a look at [eth gas station.](https://ethgasstation.info/)

If you supply more gas than required in creating a contract, the excess gas will be refunded. So try sending the gas a bit higher(but not too high) than that estimated by remix.

> After creation of my new coin "Ghost", and when someone want to send
>   10 Ghosts to another one, what about the fees of transaction, will it
>   be in ETH or Ghost?

The transaction fee will always be in ethers and the transaction fee could be estimated in the similar fashion as for contract.

> after I deploy the smart contract on mist what the next ?
>   After you deploy taken successfully. You could design a UI for users to interact with the coin or try adding your coin on some exchanges or do whatever you designed your coin for.

Answer (score 0):

1. Here's a pretty recent article that should give you some idea of how much it could cost you to deploy the contract: https://hackernoon.com/costs-of-a-real-world-ethereum-contract-2033511b3214
2. Having a user send another user your Ghost token implies a transaction. Transactions are paid in eth, not your token. (You could have these transactions also include a fee that goes back to the contract, but that doesn't have to do with the logic of the transaction per se, but with the logic that you program into your Token.
3. Once your contract is deployed you will have to provide users for a way to interact with it. You will want to develop a web app that can call the functions you exposed in your contract.

I recommend you read the Solidity documentation and get familiar with it, as well as first testing everything on a testnet before worrying about the costs associated with deploying a contract.